# MvvmCross - request for clarification regarding app structure

Tags: android, ios, architecture, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

We're developing a prototype using MvvmCross. Eventually we'll add Xamarin to support iOS/Droid, but for now we're starting with a Win Store App.

I suspect what I'm asking is fairly obvious, but some clarification on latest best practices would be much appreciated.

Traditionally we'd build apps where there was a "frame" of some kind that held common menus, footers, etc. The "pages" of the app would be moved in and out of this frame as required. With MvvmCross we construct entirely new and separate views to match each viewmodel (at least by default). It seems wrong to me to have to copy such things as a common AppBar (in the Store App case) into each view manually. I know there are ways to manage this using "standard" Store App patterns (same on other platforms), but what is the standard, recommended (hopefully not too complex) approach people are using with MvvmCross?

Comment: Not sure what the standard xaml and c# ways are, but I'd imagine they are the same regardless of the mvvm library you are using. It's an orthogonal issue?

Comment: So do I override a presenter or something in order to have common portions of the app (visible in all views) represented by their own viewmodel? Compound viewmodels in the same view?

Comment: ViewModels are just C# classes. Views are just UI controls. You can organise them exactly as you do "Traditionally". Sorry - I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for at all - if you've got specific code questions, they are easy. But if you are asking for best practice for "any app", then I'm not sure such a thing should exist.